# How to access font-family defined in nested class?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, postcss

We have a scenario where we are namespacing entire stylesheet using postcss-nested plugin.

From:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:my-font;
  src:url('data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GR...') format("woff");
}

.label {
  font-family: my-font;
  font-weight:normal;
  visibility:visible;
}
```

To:

```
.wrapper {
  @font-face {
    font-family:my-font;
    src:url('data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GR...') format("woff");
  }
}
.wrapper .label {
  font-family: my-font;
  font-weight:normal;
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Using:

```
postcss([require('postcss-nested')]).process(`.wrapper { ${plainCSS} }`, { parser: safe });
```

The above class `label` couldn't access `my-font` when nested. Is there way to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bubbling font-face to top level css has been fixed and released it in v3.0.0 with this [PR](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested/pull/69)

Answer (score 2):

postcss-nested will not handle the special case of nested `@font-face`. The processed output of what you have above will be the following invalid CSS:

```
@font-face {
    .wrapper {
        font-family: my-font;
        src:url('data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GR...') format("woff");
    }
}

.wrapper .label {
    font-family: my-font;
    font-weight:normal;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

`@font-face` has to be at the top level of the CSS file, so
you'll have to declare the nested font-face outside of the wrapper:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:my-font;
    src:url('data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GR...') format("woff");
}

.wrapper .label {
    font-family: my-font;
    font-weight:normal;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using **[postcss-scss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss)**, you can nest it along with `@root` -- which will place the `@font-face` at the top level of the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    @at-root {
        @font-face {
            font-family:my-font;
            src:url('data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GR...') format("woff");
        }
    }
}
.wrapper .label {
    font-family: my-font;
    font-weight:normal;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

The processed output will be:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: my-font;
    src: url("data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GR...") format("woff");
}

.wrapper .label {
    font-family: my-font;
    font-weight: normal;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. CSS in question was generated from plain css using postcss and we are not using sass. Will also update my question.